# what client_secret.json file is it required for google drive files access

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, pydrive

I am getting this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 388, in LoadClientConfigFile
    raise InvalidConfigError('Invalid client secrets file %s' % error)
pydrive.settings.InvalidConfigError: Invalid client secrets file ('Error opening file', 'client_secrets.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)
```

all I want is to list files and folders using pydrive !

I tried creating credentials but On consent page its showing unverified status.

from the credential page under  `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs` tab I downloaded created credentials and downloaded crediential file `secret_json_[.....].json` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html#authentication) for `pyDrive`:

> Click ‘Download JSON’ on the right side of Client ID to download `client_secret_<really long ID>.json`.
>
> The downloaded file has all authentication information of your application. Rename the file to `client_secrets.json` and place it in your working directory.

So probably you are lacking the last step of renaming the file and placing it in the working directory.

---

> I tried creating credentials but On consent page its showing unverified status.

This should not matter at all, unverified just means that you are trying to access sensitive scopes and until Google verifies your application there would be an extra screen indicating that it is a [unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865). Is okay for personal/development use.